# Excel VBA InputBox value is not a date

Tags: vba, excel, date, user-input

I have a user input box where you type in a string, annoyingly this string looks like a date `00/00/0000` and excel reformats it as such.
When the value can't be a date ex. `18/19/4561` (month can't be 18 or 19) it displays it correctly.
But whenever it can be seen as a possible date it switches things around.

I've tried setting the value as a string rather than nothing but excel still changes it when putting it in the page.

When I try manually inputting it in the cell or equal the values from a manually entered cell it works fine.

But whenever I get it from the inputbox it messes with it. Even when I hard code the string to a variable (`x = "05/06/4564"`) it switches things around.

How do I force excel to leave the string as is?

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as "Accepted" if it has solved your problem. Thanks

Comment: Have you declared x as a string?  And have you tried the `Cstr()` function?

Comment: @TMH8885: Yes I did try try both, and neither work. (mentioned the first one in my question btw) I believe the problem here wasn't VBA's way of handling the string. But Excel trying to be smart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefix the value with a single apostrophe and Excel will interpret it as a string.

Eg `'18/19/4561`

Also, have you tried setting the cell format to `Text`

Comment: Damnit so dumb of me, I've added a .NumberFormat = "@" before it runs and works fine now. Thanks. the apostrophe thing wouldn't really work for me as I would have to constantly filter that out and in again when doing something with it.